# If a variable exists return it, else load and return it

Tags: swift

I want to do like below with settar and getter:

- if a variable already on memory, return it.
- if a variable isn't load, load and return it.

Can you write it simply?

```
// Error code
class Person : NSObject {
    let personId : String
    init(personId: String) {
        self.personId = personId
    }
    public var name : String? {
        // The key is not static. It is decided dynamically.
        let keyName = "name-" + self.personId
        get {
            // If `name` exists, return it.
            if name != nil { return name }
            // Else load from `UserDefaults`
            return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: keyName)
        }
        set {
            name = UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: keyName)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't achieve what you are asking using only a variable, because [`computed properties`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025340/property-getters-and-setters) don't have any storage in the instance. So you have to introduce a private variable to save the value `in memory`:

```
class Person : NSObject {
  public let personId : String
  private var _name: String?

  init(personId: String) {
    self.personId = personId
  }

  public var name : String? {
    get {
      let keyName = "name-" + self.personId
      return _name != nil ? _name : UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: keyName)
    }

    set {
      let keyName = "name-" + self.personId
      UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: keyName)
      _name = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no need for `_name`. Just return `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: keyName)` in the getter. That's it. No need to check if it exists.

Comment: Maiko was asking for: "if a variable is already in memory", UserDefaults is not enough since https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410584/ios-speed-of-reading-nsuserdefaults-vs-variables

Comment: Oh, I see, `computed properties` don't have any storage, I understood. 
Thank you.
Yes, I didn't want to access `UserDefaults` every time because reading from disc was slow.

Comment: Glad you found it useful. Feel free to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: @MaikoOhkawa But UserDefaults will not be read from disc every time. Don't worry about speed until you actually have a problem to deal with.

Comment: Oh, I see. `UserDefault` control access to disc properly. That's great. I use `UserDefault` directly, thanks rmaddy! If you know the documentation about it, I want to read.

Comment: documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults also you may want to call `synchronize()`, after you write something inside `UserDefaults` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize

Comment: I had overlooked! `UserDefaults caches the information to avoid having to open the user’s defaults database each time you need a default value.` I had understood correctly and call `synchronize()`, thank you!

Comment: The documentation says `synchronize()` is `unnecessary and shouldn't be used.` Recently it seems unnecessary. :)

Comment: @MaikoOhkawa Regarding calling `synchronize()` - please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808072/when-and-why-should-you-use-nsuserdefaultss-synchronize-method/40809748?s=1|43.0066#40809748